# FileUploadQuestion using the Google Forms API

Tags: google-api, google-forms, google-workspace, google-forms-api

I would require to use the `FileUploadQuestion` endpoint for an internal automatic process. However, this endpoint appears to not be supported by the API for the moment. This is weird since it exists an [API route to be able to use this](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms#fileuploadquestion).

**Do you know when should I be able to use it?**

*During this time, I will find alternative solution using another forms solutions*

Comment: “_Do you know when should I be able to use it?_” The users on StackOverflow are not employees of Google, nor do they have access to information that is not available to the general public. You should ask Google.

Comment: @Tedinoz I'd love to, but Google specifically recommends asking the question on StackOverflow

Comment: How thoughtful of Google! Well, the question has been asked, we shall see whether anyone can provide an answer.